# How can one go about integrating messaging into an Ubuntu Touch App?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, messaging-menu

Hi I am wondering what is the best way to integrate a "Sharing" feature into an app built for Ubuntu Touch (as well as the desktop).  I am wondering if there is some sort of documentation available (searching didn't turn up anything for me).
I want to be able to tap (or click) on an area of text and share it through a choice of any available messaging options.  For phone, I'd like to support Text messaging, E-mail, social media, and any other options.  For desktop I'd like to support everything in the messaging menu (whatever the user has installed that correlates).  Is there a standard "Sharing" component?  Is there a way to dynamically support all messaging across all devices, with all new messaging services that are installed to be present in a popover menu?
It would also be nice to support sharing of images (for my program it would be maps, or charts) in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually once the Ubuntu SDK reached 1.0 they posted this goodie which offers the API for online accounts.
http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/Ubuntu.OnlineAccounts/
And additionally
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/messaging-menu/
offers the integration into the messaging menu on the desktop.
I assume this API will be changing as the platform matures...
However, this is the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Messaging Menu Documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/messaging-menu/), you can get a list of applications registered to the Messaging Menu. From there, you can send your text to any registered applications, although these will define their own actions, which do not seem to be standardized yet. Also, the API is still not fixed AFAIK, so you might need to change your code for each new major release.

Comment: I mainly wanted the info about Ubuntu Touch, rather than just the messaging menu, but I found the info (because it was posted when the SDK reach 1.0) my main concern was Ubuntu Touch, with the desktop as secondary (because both will be integrated when Mir can be usable on the desktop)